# List of registered domain names

Tags: untagged

Where can I find a list of domain names that I can download in a text file? I looked around and I found many sites with lists of expired domain names or domain names that will expire soon, but that's not what I need, I need a list of CURRENTLY REGISTERED domain names. The closest I found was this site (hxxp://www.list-of-domains.org/), but what I'm looking for ideally is just a plain list of registered domains and not some web links split across many pages full with ads and no text file. I know it's possible, after all how do these sites get the list of domains that they use? Where can I find such a list?

Comment: Quite apart from this having nothing to do with system administration, the only thing that I can think of when reading the question is that this is for spamming. Feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: I use the master TLD list to find available domains.

Comment: You can get a list from http://www.verisign.com/domain-name-services/domain-information-center/tld-zone-access/index.html

Comment: These guys also sell the lists: http://www.premiumdrops.com/zones.html

Comment: Cross-Exchange dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/a/307590/1449525

Answer (score 6):

You cannot download a list of all registered domains.  There is no such list.  DNS is a hierarchal, delegated and distributed service where TLDs (Top Level Domains, e.g. .com and .uk) are managed by disparate registrar authorities.  Although changes to ICANN policies appear to be curbing the widespread use of "domain parking", it is still quite common for automated services to be constantly registering new domains and re-registered expired ones.  For this reason alone, it's virtually impossible for there to be a single authoritative list of registered domains.

Comment: So how does the site I posted have a huge list of domains? I don't need a complete list, I just need a massive list of millions of domain names.

Comment: Like ceejayoz said, probably by crawling the web or perhaps by paying the registrars for them. The point is, there is no master list, if you want a list you have to either build it yourself or buy it from someone who's done that work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're going to use that data for, you can get a bulk copy of the ARIN whois database. More information [here](https://www.arin.net/resources/request/bulkwhois.html). I would recommend researching / contacting the other [RIRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) for information concerning their bulk WHOIS policies.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it's possible, after all how do these sites get the list of domains that they use? Where can I find such a list?

There is no such list. Sites that have large lists probably collected them by crawling (similar to how Google finds web pages) or by purchasing them from the bigger registrars.

Comment: There is such a list. The registry needs such a list to let the registrar know if a domain e.g. foobar.com can be registered or if it already has been registered.

Comment: @Pacerier First, most registrars wouldn't consult a list, but a WHOIS record just like we do ourselves to check availability. Second, even if there were such a list, there are many TLDs with different responsible parties, each of whom would have their own separate list. Third, such a list would not be publicly available.

Comment: Public availability is not what we are talking about: We are talking about existence. Next, each registry will have it's own list of course. And lastly, registrars **do** consult the central list  either directly or indirectly when registering for new domain names, otherwise, there **will** be clashes.

Comment: @Pacerier The question being answered is "Where can I find a list of domain names that I can download in a text file?" No such list exists, plain and simple. Many private, partial lists exist at the various registrars (no single "central list", the .com registrar won't have the canonical list of the .nyc domains) but again, they are not downloadable per the question asked.